# Возможно ли "венчать завершение" чего-либо?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов

> Его скульптурная композиция в прямом и переносном смысле венчает
>   завершение работ по фасаду – фигуры двух гениев удерживают знак семьи
>   Корсини – в самом верху триумфальной арки, над торжественной надписью.

Каждое тире, имхо, играет свою роль; может быть, после "по фасаду" двоеточие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Венчает завершение работ" - речевая ошибка, плеоназм.

По Ожегову и Шведовой  венчать -

2. перен., что. Находиться на верху чего-н. *Башню венчает рубиновая звезда.* Герб семьи Корсини может венчать композицию или фасад.
3. перен., что. Заканчивать собой что-н., успешно завершать (высок.). *Конец венчает дело*.

Получается "завершать завершение", "заканчивать завершение" - ошибка. Так что перестраивать предложение всё равно придётся.

А насчёт замены тире двоеточием - нормально.  БСП - второе предложение поясняет первое.

Answer (score 1):

< *в прямом и переносном смысле венчает завершение работ*

В *прямом смысле* "венчать" означает исключительно возложение венка на голову, *в переносном* же смысле одна конструкция может быть увенчана другой, поменьше, но не может венчать "завершение работ" (действие не "венчают") - это элемент фразеологии прорабов по поводу сроков текущего строительства; в данном случае уместно говорить лишь о *завершённости композиции* и т. п.

Второе тире - лишнее: оно создаёт ложное впечатление вставки, в то время как на его месте нет разрыва смыслов (там простое уточнение); вместо первого тире, видимо, возможно и двоеточие.

> Его скульптурная группа придаёт композиции фасада впечатляющую
>   завершённость [или "достойнейшим образом венчает общую композицию
>   фасада"] – фигуры двух гениев удерживают знак семьи Корсини в самом
>   верху триумфальной арки, над торжественной надписью.

Answer (score 1):

Его скульптурная композиция завершает убранство триумфальной арки венчающим её гербом семьи Корсини, который удерживают вверху над торжественной надписью два гения.

Фигуры держат, фасад арки, венчает завершение... Нелепые сочетания.